# Conversion failed for string ISO to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to convert a varchar(255) to datetime in SQL. I found this example:

```
DECLARE @IsoDate nvarchar(255)
SET @IsoDate = '2010-03-16T19:20:30.45123+01:00'

-- CONVERT TO DATETIME in SQL 2008
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(datetimeoffset, @IsoDate) AS datetime) as SQL2008
```

and it works perfectly. As I want to change the column format of a whole column, I tried

```
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(datetimeoffset, [col1]) AS datetime) 
from [table]
```

but it gives me an error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
I don't get what the problem is, the only way it worked using the column is

```
SELECT CAST(Left([col1]),18) AS datetime) 
from [table]
```

but I would prefer not to cut the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
SELECT *
from [table]
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(datetimeoffset, [col1]) IS NULL
```

to see which values are causing issues.

If your version (since you have a comment with SQL Server 2008) is not supporting `TRY_CONVERT` and `TRY_CAST` you can select part of the records to find the issues using a loop/where clause.

Answer (score 0):

> but I would prefer not to cut the string.

Why? When converting `DateTimeOffset` to `DateTime`, the time zone information gets truncated anyway (see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#converting-datetimeoffset-data-type-to-other-date-and-time-types)), and since you've stated this solves your problem, it means that the only places where your string content is problematic is somewhere in that part of the string.

Also, since your string is ISO8601, you can safely use `cast` instead of `convert` (what's the point of using `convert` if you're not going to use the `style` parameter anyway?) - or better yet, use `try_cast` (unless you're working with a version lower than 2012, which in that case you should consider upgrading since it's the oldest version still supported) - so:

```sql
SELECT CAST(TRY_CAST([col1] AS datetimeoffset) AS datetime2(7))
FROM [table]
```

That being said, it would be better store time-zone aware datetime values in a `DateTimeOffset` data type - and other datetime values in `DateTime2` data type ([which is better than `DateTime` in every way](https://hockeygeekgirl.com/2011/06/22/why-you-should-never-use-datetime-again/)).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is failing because you have bad values.  You can ignore them using `try_convert()`:

```
SELECT CAST(TRY_CONVERT(datetimeoffset, [col1]) AS datetime) 
FROM [table]
```

This is supported in all supported versions of SQL Server.

Because the timezone is ignored in this process, you might as well simply use:

```
select try_convert(datetime, left(col1, 23))
```